# odd sourcing bash behavior with functions and ANSI control sequences

Tags: bash, terminal

```
function tc() { echo -ne "\033]0;$1\007"; }

function justecho() { echo z$1$1z; }

HOSTNAME=$(hostname)

tc hello #works
#tc $(hostname)
justecho $(hostname) #works
```

The above is saved in a file called testbash.txt and called as follows:
source testbash.txt

The commented out line does not work as expected. The other two function calls work as expected. How do I pass the host name to the function tc? TC alters the tab name in terminal window, and works as expected if a literal string is passed (i.e. tc hello). If code is unclear, I can provide more information.

Comment: What about that line doesn't work exactly? What is your hostname? Add `set -x` to the top of this script and add `| cat -v; echo` to the end of each of the test lines and then show the output.

Comment: `tc "$HOSTNAME"` should work, but so should the commented out version. Good luck.

Comment: this is in .bashrc file. I did some experimenting with substring. As long as string does not equal machine name, all works, title changes. If string equals machine name, nothing is displayed (ssh). Thinking this is iterm2, xterm issue. I am going to do some more testing.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what exactly is broken without more information (which shell you are using, what your hostname is, what the output of the non working line is).

A possible cause is that your ANSI control sequence is broken (incomplete) and the string that follows it is partially or completely swallowed by it, depending on your terminal's implementation and on what the string is.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `\033]0;`. I'm guessing it has to do with colorization or font size, in which case you are probably looking for `\033[0m` (the "reset color" sequence) instead. Control sequences end with '`m`' and use '`;`' as an internal separator between possible arguments (e.g. `\033[0;32;40m` specifies a font width of 0, foreground color of 32/green and background color of 40/black).

There are many resources online where you can learn about possible control sequences. For example: [Using ANSI color codes](http://www.linuxfocus.org/English/May2004/article335.shtml).

As general advice, keep these in mind as well:

- quote the argument to tc: `tc "$(hostname)"` (I haven't heard of a hostname containing spaces yet, but it can't hurt).
- be aware of the `-n` argument to `echo`, making it not output a new line. This may confuse you when you are looking at the output on a terminal, especially if you have a fancier prompt with control characters which might "eat" your current line. To verify this, generate a new line after you call the function: `tc "$(hostname)"; echo` - and see if it looks better.
- make sure your `hostname` command exists and is callable
- know/plan for the purpose of your script. If this is ever going to be used as input for another command, the control sequences will most likely cause undesired behavior. Even doing `testbash.txt | less` will look wrong, not to mention using `grep` or other parsing tools.

*Edit*: Your control sequence is meant to set the terminal title and looks correct, as pointed out in the comment section. Please try the other suggestions above and/or provide additional information.

Comment: If you want to learn what the `ESC ] ...` sequences do, look for `OSC` in the xterm control sequences document: http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html - the sequence in the question is correct; the only mistake was calling it "ANSI"

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about that category of control codes.